# from foreach to array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a script that receive POST information (2 id's from another page) which is stored in an array I want to be able to get those two id's and save them into two seperate variables. I have found a way to collect them in a foreach loop but how can extract them and store them as to seperate variables. 
I have tried with this code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['res'])) {
                foreach($_POST['res'] as $result_id) {      
                    $new_id[] = $result_id;
                }
            }

            echo $new_id[1];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $new_id[2];
```

but it only print out the first one.

Comment: PHP array start with 0. You need to use `$new_id[0]` and `$new_id[1]`

Comment: Because array indexes start at 0

Comment: _note_: `$new_id[0]` is the same as `$_POST['res'][0]` - but without the foreach

Comment: Always check the output first before . do `var_dump( $new_id);` to see output result.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works. :-)   jh1711: Should you give an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: and if you want seperate variable names (and you don't want it, actually....): use [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: Arh. Ok. Thanks Jeff. I will look into list() method.

Comment: _and_ your foreach is the same as if you simply did `$new_id = $_POST['res'];`

Comment: @Kenneth there is no reason to prefer an answer from me, just because I was the first person to write something. If you like any answer given as an answer just accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes should start with 0. So Just carefully observe your array using

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['res']);
echo '</pre>'
```

This will give you a sense of how the array looks like, so you will be having better understanding of how to read/retrieve values from array.
In this situation, I feel safe to say (by observing your question) that your array has two values and I hope they are at index 0 and 1, If you haven't modified them.

As until you play around and change it, at default array starts from key 0 and goes on, so changing the last two lines should get you your result.

```
if(!empty($_POST['res'])) {
            foreach($_POST['res'] as $result_id) {      
                $new_id[] = $result_id;
            }
        }

        echo $new_id[0];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $new_id[1];
```

and yes, last three lines can be combined into one like this :

```
echo $new_id[0].'<br>'.$new_id[1];
```

and In your code, If you don't get POST values, it's going to throw warning of Undefined Index.

You need to wrap all of these echo's within the condition or you can setup an else for your loop.

```
 if(!empty($_POST['res'])) {
            foreach($_POST['res'] as $result_id) {      
                $new_id[] = $result_id;
            }
    echo $new_id[0].'<br>'.$new_id[1];    
 }
```